# MySql Combine data from remote databases servers

Tags: mysql, remote-server

I have a mysql database at my primary office and 4 off site servers that are taken to events and collect customer data. When I bring a server back to the home office I need to send all data from the off-site database to the primary database without overwriting the existing data, so that I can clear the remote database and send it fresh to the next event.

I looked into mysqldump and it always drops all the previous data, which would be very bad.

If anyone can help point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Notes:
The off-site servers have no internet connection at events and the off-site servers are not connected to the LAN when at the office.

Ultimately I am trying to figure out how to do this so I can throw it in a script.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this kind of a maneuver with a small program (written in Java perhaps) that reads data from a temporary DB and inserts it to the primary DB since it would give me full control over what gets copied and what does not.

If you want to use mysqldump for this, then I think the following should work:

1. dump the database that's been in an event to a file using mysqldump
2. create a temporary DB to your primary database instance (so you have primary_db and temporary_db that are structurally identical and in the same mysql-instance)
3. load the dump into the temporary DB
4. run **[INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)** from temporary DB to primary DB:

   INSERT INTO primary_db.customer (name,address) SELECT name, address FROM temporary_db.customer

Comment: I was thinking  about just making a quick vb app that will store all the data in a dataset and INSERT in a for loop threw all the records. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure behavior of mysqldump related to drops or replace/insert in command line.

try

```
mysqldump --help
```

Also you can use [INSERT SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html)

You can also use SELECT CONCAT (to create CSV) and [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) to import CSV statements.

Comment: I'll take a look at csv files. Thank you